# Why can't I use double colon operator with dplyr when the dataset is in sparklyr?

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, sparklyr

A reproducible example (adapted from @forestfanjoe's answer):

```
library(dplyr)
library(sparklyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")

df <- data.frame(id = 1:100, PaymentHistory = runif(n = 100, min = -1, max = 2))

df <- copy_to(sc, df, "payment")

> head(df)
# Source: spark<?> [?? x 2]
     id PaymentHistory
* <int>          <dbl>
1     1         -0.138
2     2         -0.249
3     3         -0.805
4     4          1.30 
5     5          1.54 
6     6          0.936

fix_PaymentHistory <- function(df){df %>% dplyr::mutate(PaymentHistory = dplyr::if_else(PaymentHistory < 0, 0, dplyr::if_else(PaymentHistory > 1,1, PaymentHistory)))}

df %>% fix_PaymentHistory
```

The error is:

```
 Error in dplyr::if_else(PaymentHistory < 0, 0, dplyr::if_else(PaymentHistory >  : 
 object 'PaymentHistory' not found
```

I'm using the scope operator because I'm afraid that the name in `dplyr` will clash with some of the user-defined code. Note that `PaymentHistory` is a column variable in `df`.

The same error is not present when running the following code:

```
fix_PaymentHistory <- function(df){
    df %>% mutate(PaymentHistory = if_else(PaymentHistory < 0, 0,if_else(PaymentHistory > 1,1, PaymentHistory)))
}
> df %>% fix_PaymentHistory
# Source: spark<?> [?? x 2]
      id PaymentHistory
 * <int>          <dbl>
 1     1         0     
 2     2         0     
 3     3         0     
 4     4         1     
 5     5         1     
 6     6         0.936 
 7     7         0     
 8     8         0.716 
 9     9         0     
10    10         0.0831
# ... with more rows
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: seems you were not using dplyr's `if_else` in the first place, are you currently using another package with an `if_else` function included? or did you define your own? what does F1 on if_else show you?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue on an example data

Comment: The only package I'm using is dplyr and sparklyr. I'm certain that if_else is from dplyr.

Comment: So this just to confirm this only happens if you use a data source from `sparklyr`? If I use the same function with just a standard data.frame, I don't get an error (I don't have `library(sparklyr)` installed so I can't test with that.

Comment: @MrFlick Yes, when I ran the same code with native data.frame, everything is fine.

Comment: @MrFlick MCVE without `sparklyr`: `library(magrittr); db <- dplyr::src_sqlite(":memory:", TRUE); dplyr::copy_to(db, mtcars); db %>% dplyr::tbl("mtcars") %>% dplyr::mutate(dplyr::if_else(mpg < 20, 1, 0))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR** Because your code doesn't use `dplyr::if_else` at all.

`sparklyr`, when used as in the example, treats Spark as yet another database and issues queries using [`dbplyr` SQL translation layer](https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/sql-translation.html).

In this context `if_else` is no treated as a function, but an identifier which is converted to SQL primitives:

```
dbplyr::translate_sql(if_else(PaymentHistory < 0, 0,if_else(PaymentHistory > 1,1, PaymentHistory)))
# <SQL> CASE WHEN ("PaymentHistory" < 0.0) THEN (0.0) WHEN NOT("PaymentHistory" < 0.0) THEN (CASE WHEN ("PaymentHistory" > 1.0) THEN (1.0) WHEN NOT("PaymentHistory" > 1.0) THEN ("PaymentHistory") END) END
```

However if you pass a fully qualified named, it will circumvent this mechanism, try to evaluate the function, and ultimately fail, because the database columns are not in the scope.

> I'm afraid that the name in dplyr will clash with some of the user-defined code.

As you see, there is no need for dplyr to be in scope here at all - functions called in `sparklyr` pipelines are either translated to corresponding SQL constructs, or if there is no specific translation rule in place, passed as-is and resolved by Spark SQL engine (this path is used to invoke [Spark functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$)).

Of course this mechanism is not specific to `sparklyr` and you're likely to see the same behavior using other table backed by a database:

```
library(magrittr)

db <- dplyr::src_sqlite(":memory:", TRUE)
dplyr::copy_to(db, mtcars)

db %>% dplyr::tbl("mtcars") %>% dplyr::mutate(dplyr::if_else(mpg < 20, 1, 0))
```

```
Error in dplyr::if_else(mpg < 20, 1, 0) : object 'mpg' not found
```